# Abstract tree-map function

Tags: lisp, tree, scheme, sicp

> Exercise 2.31.  Abstract your answer
>   to exercise 2.30 to produce a
>   procedure tree-map with the property
>   that square-tree could be defined as
>
> ```
> (define (square-tree tree) (tree-map square tree))
> ```

I wrote the following solution:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (tree-map f tree)
  (cond ((null? tree) null)
        ((pair? tree)
         (cons (tree-map f (car tree))
               (tree-map f (cdr tree))))
        (else (f tree))))

(define (map-tree-map f tree)
  (map (lambda (subtree)
         (if (pair? subtree)
             (cons (map-tree-map f (car subtree))
                   (map-tree-map f (cdr subtree)))
             (f subtree)))
         tree))

(define (square-tree tree) (tree-map square tree))
(define (map-square-tree tree) (map-tree-map square tree))

(define a (list 1 1 (list (list 2 3) 1 2)))
```

Can this be improved in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your direct definition of `tree-map` looks good.

The version using `map` may be written more succinctly (with the recursive portion factored out) as follows:

```
(define (tree-map f tree)
  (define (rec tree)
    (map (lambda (subtree)
           ((if (pair? subtree) rec f) subtree))
         tree))
  (rec tree))
```